# How to read or interpret Lambda in Lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to understand nested lambdas:

```
f = lambda x, y: y(y(x))
g = lambda x : lambda y: x(y)
print( f(lambda x: x+1, g) (4) )
```

I was told that this code printed "5". How is this explained, and how should one parse the `(4)` in the last line?

From my understanding of lambda, if,

```
h = lambda a, b : a+b
```

i know that `print(h(1,2))` will give 3
as a = 1, b =2, and proceed with a+b = 1+2 =3

Comment: nice question!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`f(lambda x: x+1, g)` ultimately returns another function. *That* function is then called with 4 as its argument to produce the final result of 5.

---

Let `h = lambda x: x + 1`, because this becomes a mess to trace otherwise.

First, we apply `f` to `h` and `g`.

```
f(h, g)(4) == (lambda x,y: y(y(x))(h, g)(4)
           == g(g(h))(4)
```

Next, we'll evaluate the inner call to `g`:

```
g(g(h))(4) == g((lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(h))(4)
           == g(lambda y: h(y))(4)
           == g(h)(4)
```

The last step is an example of *eta reduction*, to use a term from lambda calculus: a function that applies a second function to an argument is equivalent to the second function itself.

Finally, we evaluate `g(h)` again the same way, which finally gets us to an expression that doesn't involve passing a function as an argument, and lets us get a final answer.

```
g(h)(4) == (lambda y: h(y))(4)
        == h(4)
        == (lambda x: x + 1)(4)
        == 4 + 1
        == 5
```

Comment: is it possible to give a step by step analysis? I'm still quite new to this so it's confusing me

Comment: Done :) It was tricky enough that I wanted to get the TL;DR version up before tackling the precise evaluation.

Comment: Python 2 used to supply the uncurried version of `g`; it was called `apply`: `apply(f, x) == f(x)`.

Comment: I think `g` is a red herring, it's just an identity function (in higher-order function space), no?

Comment: `x` is constrained to be a beta abstraction, so it's just a hair more than an identity function. But yeah, it's pretty close.

Comment: I think parentheses should be used in the last block to avoid ambiguity when trying to understand what's happening. `lambda y: h(y)(4)` is not the same as `(lambda y: h(y))(4)`.

Comment: @init_js Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a go at expanding the logic. First, I'm going to rename some argument names to differentiate your two functions:

```
f = lambda i, j: j(j(i))
g = lambda x: lambda y: x(y)
```

Now `f(lambda x: x+1, g)` is equivalent to:

```
h = (lambda i, j: j(j(i)))(lambda x: x+1, g)
```

Here, a function being used as an argument. This is fine, as functions are first-class objects in Python and can be passed around in this way. So evaluating this:

```
h = g(g(lambda x: x+1))
```

But `g` is nothing fancy, it simply takes a function and applies it to an argument. It can be considered an "identity" function with a function as an argument. You can get rid of `g` altogether. So we have:

```
h = (lambda x: x+1)
```

In other words, `h` just adds one to any input.

Answer (score 0):

`h = lambda x: x+1`  is a function that returns 1 more than the value passed to it. 
It is equivalent to:

```
def h(x):
    return x+1
```

`f = lambda x, y: y(y(x))` is a function which takes a value and a function as a pair of arguments and evaluates function(function(value)). 
It is equivalent to:

```
def f(x, y):
    return y(y(x))
```

`g = lambda x: lambda y: x(y)` is a decorator function that returns a new function based on function passed to it.
It is equivalent to:

```
def g(x):
    def new_func(y):
        return x(y)
    return new_func
```

---

the given lambda expressions,

```
f = lambda x, y: y(y(x))
g = lambda x : lambda y: x(y)
```

expression to evaluate

```
   f(lambda x: x+1, g) (4)
```

this reduces to

```
=> g(g(lambda x: x+1)) (4)
```

now note that g(g(lambda x: x+1)) returns a function g(lambda x: x+1)

```
=> g(lambda x: x+1) (4)
```

now here g(lambda x: x+1) again returns a function (x+1)

```
=> (x+1) (4)
```

this evaluates to 4+1 i.e 5

```
=> 5
```